# Background color for a range of lines in Minted

Tags: minted, backgrounds

I have a long piece of code that highlight with `minted`.

I would like to have a background only around a block of code. How can I achieve that?

I tried to use something like `escapeinside=||` to create a color box.

In this example we want to put a background to central part, between the `\colorbox{green}...` and `\end{minipage}}` commands.

```latex
\begin{minted}[linenos=true,escapeinside=||,breaklines=true]{cpp}
...
    if (is_continuous<T>::value && value.size() == 0)
        ar.write(path, static_cast<typename scalar_type<std::vector<T, A> >::type const *>(NULL), std::vector<std::size_t>());
    else if (is_continuous<T>::value) {
        |\colorbox{green}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}|
        std::vector<std::size_t> extent(get_extent(value));
        std::copy(extent.begin(), extent.end(), std::back_inserter(size));
        std::copy(extent.begin(), extent.end(), std::back_inserter(chunk));
        std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(offset), extent.size(), 0);
        ar.write(path, get_pointer(value), size, chunk, offset);
        |\end{minipage}}|
    } else if (value.size() == 0)
        ar.write(path, static_cast<int const *>(NULL), std::vector<std::size_t>());
    else if (is_vectorizable(value)) {
...
\end{minted}
```

However, this does not compile, I think because the `escapeinside` command cannot leave open blocks.

Any idea for achieving the desired behavior?

thanks.

Comment: Can one put three `minted` environments directly after one another, where only the desired ones have a background?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried it out (see possible answer posted below).

Comment: Probably you can insert some negative space between the environments, like `\vspace{-3.5mm}`?

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution (thanks Tom Bombadil) would split the code in more `minted` blocks. However, this also shows some problem. (see below)

What I tried is the following code

```latex
\begin{minted}[linenos=true,fontsize=\footnotesize,breaklines=true]{cpp}
    ...
    if (is_continuous<T>::value && value.size() == 0)
        ar.write(path, static_cast<typename scalar_type<std::vector<T, A> >::type const *>(NULL), std::vector<std::size_t>());
    else if (is_continuous<T>::value) {
\end{minted}
\begin{minted}[linenos=true,fontsize=\footnotesize,breaklines=true,firstnumber=last,bgcolor=YellowGreen]{cpp}
        /* BEGIN BLOCK 1 */
        std::vector<std::size_t> extent(get_extent(value));
        std::copy(extent.begin(), extent.end(), std::back_inserter(size));
        std::copy(extent.begin(), extent.end(), std::back_inserter(chunk));
        std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(offset), extent.size(), 0);
        ar.write(path, get_pointer(value), size, chunk, offset);
        /* END BLOCK 1 */
\end{minted}
\begin{minted}[linenos=true,fontsize=\footnotesize,breaklines=true,firstnumber=last]{cpp}
    } else if (value.size() == 0)
        ar.write(path, static_cast<int const *>(NULL), std::vector<std::size_t>());
    else if (is_vectorizable(value)) {
    ...
\end{minted}
```

which results in
[image]

Here the problems are:

1. The space separation between blocks
2. The numbers have a different offset when there is a background.

Is it possible to work around these issues?

Comment: you can work around the second problem by adding `bgcolor=white` to the code blocks which have no bgcolor. This also reduces the first problem.

Comment: my comment referred to minted version 1.7. Regarding minted 2.4 please see my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/376090/120953).