# Behind text but on top of beamer background

Tags: beamer, eso-pic

I would like to use [Henri Menke's answer from another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376222/120953) with beamer. Unfortunately the tikzpicture is not visible. As pointed out [here](https://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2007-March/008035.html) this is because the tikzpicture is behind beamer's background. So it would become visible when making the background transparent `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}`. But this slide is supposed to have the same beamer background like all other slides, too.

How can I position the tikzpicture behind the minted text but on top of the beamer background?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{latex}{linenos, frame=lines, autogobble, breaklines}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)] \node (#1) {\vphantom{I}};}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newcommand{\colorPreamble}{blue!10}
\newcommand{\colorDocument}{green!10}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \twocolumn
    \begin{latexcode*}{escapeinside=||}
        |\tikzmark{n}|\documentclass{article}

        [...]
        |\tikzmark{c}|
        \begin{document}
            [...]
        |\tikzmark{s}|\end{document}
    \end{latexcode*}
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \path[overlay, fill=\colorPreamble] (n.north) rectangle ([xshift=\linewidth] c.south);
            \path[overlay, fill=\colorDocument] (c.south) rectangle ([xshift=\linewidth] s.south);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \twocolumn
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot test with `minted`, but I think you can simply add the `tikz` picture to beamers own background mechanism instead of using `eso-pic`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)] \node (#1) {\vphantom{I}};}

\newcommand{\colorPreamble}{blue!10}
\newcommand{\colorDocument}{green!10}

\begin{document}

{
    \addtobeamertemplate{background canvas}{}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \path[overlay, fill=\colorPreamble] (n.north) rectangle ([xshift=\linewidth] c.south);
      \path[overlay, fill=\colorDocument] (c.south) rectangle ([xshift=\linewidth] s.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
            \tikzmark{n}
            [...]

            \tikzmark{c}
            [...]

            \tikzmark{s}
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]